# How can I add a tooltip to my Crossrider toolbar button?

Tags: button, tooltip, toolbar, crossrider

I added button to by Crossrider extension (see snippet) but I can't see how to add a tootip when hovering over the button. Are tooltips supported?

Exmaple code in background.js:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
    appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon('icon.jpg');
    appAPI.browserAction.onClick(function() {console.log('hello world!');});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Like most HTML tags, the [title attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp) is used to add a tooltip to an element; hence, to add a tooltip to a Crossrider toolbar button you simply set its title attribute using [appAPI.browserAction.setTitle](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction-method-setTitle).

Using your snippet as a base, you can use the following example to set the tooltip to "My tooltip":

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon('icon.jpg');
  appAPI.browserAction.setTitle('My tooltip');
  appAPI.browserAction.onClick(function() {console.log('hello world!');});
});
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]